# How do i make the brush tool less antialiased?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I got art from an artist the image has these nice sharp lines like the arm below. Notice the sharpness of the black outlines. When I draw it myself, it looks like the line above, much more blurry.

I would say the artist's lines are somewhere between the brush and the pencil tool. Is there a way to draw like this in Photoshop? I'm using Photoshop 2020, but I'm on CC so i can upgrade if neccessary.

Thanks!

[image: difference between lines]

Comment: Are you using the same canvas size?

Comment: Antialiasing is a big concept. So what your asking is can you adjust the antialiasing routine of photoshop. Sure you can but are you really really commited to your stuff? Realistically i doubt your ready for this. Anyway yes indeed adobe does antialiasing wrong form a scientific and technical point of view.

Comment: Hmm... a simple method might be to just duplicate the layer the black lines are on. That will certainly reduce anti-aliasing slightly.  [See example](https://imgur.com/NMKkLsO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a brush image, something like this. I used a normal brush to make this, then I tweaked the curves to create more contrast. Then I did Select All, then *Edit > Define Brush Preset*

[image]

Here's the result. The line on top shows a normal 4px brush. Below it is the brush I made

[image]

You shouldn't resize the brush when painting though, otherwise it will just introduce the blurring problem again. You could make different brushes for different widths.

Note: One other thing you may want to consider is not using Photoshop at all for work that would be [better output as vector](https://svgshare.com/i/YsY.svg). Personally, I wouldn't even consider using Photoshop for anything like this.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks. We have an art style in our game that is handpainted and a bit sloppy/curved lines. Also I'm a programmer and not an artist, but it's great to be able to fix small things like that using that trick.

Answer (score 2):

Another trick is to turn on `Texture` setting with `Height` mode (no actual texture is needed)

Here's an example of a standard round brush and a brush with `Texture` turned on:

[image]

You can change `Depth` to adjust the effect:

[image]

On a side note with game assets you usually want to draw them at 200% or 400% of the final scale. Larger size will allow for more control and the image will look less blurry. An example of painting zoomed in and having a second window as a preview at 50% for the actual asset size:

[image]

Comment: This is a great tip too! I will definitely try that, might be quicker than to use a custom brush (the answer i accepted) which had a little weird preview shape when drawing. Thanks!

Comment: @BlueGooGames yeah creating 20-ish tool tips for different sizes might not be ideal

Answer (score 1):

A brush edge only gets so hard in Photoshop. Once you push the hardness to 100%, there's no way to further remove any anti-alising. You *can* try working at a high PPI and then reducing, but that can be guesswork more than anything.

**Vector *layers*** in Photoshop can often have a bit less anti-aliasing than brushes. You might try using the vector tools rather than brushes.

---

I'd suggest that the original sample you've posted may have been created originally *outside* of Photoshop.

**Vector artwork**.. *placed as a Smart Object into Photoshop*, then rasterized (if necessary) will have less anti-aliasing than painting directly in Photoshop.

My guess.. that's how the original was created... even the artwork itself suggests it would be easier to create in a vector application - at least the keyline.

Zoomed in to just before the pixel grid shows (300ppi file)....

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The original is drawn using Clip Studio Paint, it might have settings for that. I went for the solution with making a brush that is sharper.